# Is it possible to compare an image with a list of images? [google-cloud-vision]

Tags: google-cloud-platform, similarity, google-cloud-vision

I'm trying to compare one dog image with a bucket full of dog images and get their similarity, does anybody have some clue to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You could try out Vision API's ProductSearch: https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/docs/

You build a ProductSet of Products. You add reference images to each Product. Later, you send a query image in and it will return the most visually similar results in your ProductSet.

Comment: Using AI would be the only way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [Ruby gem](https://github.com/Nakilon/dhash-vips) that implementes two perceptual image hashing to calculate the image similarity.

```
require "dhash-vips"

hash0 = DHashVips::IDHash.fingerprint "dog.jpg"

hash1 = DHashVips::IDHash.fingerprint "dog1.jpg"
hash2 = DHashVips::IDHash.fingerprint "dog2.jpg"

puts "dog1 is this much different: #{DHashVips::IDHash.distance hash0, hash1}"
puts "dog2 is this much different: #{DHashVips::IDHash.distance hash0, hash2}"
```