# Google Cloud Vision AI how to select similar images from range of provided images

Tags: google-cloud-platform, artificial-intelligence, image-recognition, google-vision

I want to be able to select similar images using Google Cloud Vision AI out of range of images that I provide.

It seems there is [Web Detection](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-web) feature allows to show similar images across the web but I want to search across user provided images or even just within a particular website (not across entire web).

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in feature that allows you to do that on the Google Cloud Vision API, but what you can do is fetch the URL of the matching images detected across the web and filter the ones you are interested in. You can follow this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/internet-detection).

I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You could try out Vision API's ProductSearch: https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/docs/

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58402071/11201290